# Combining .net Maui WebView and other controlls on same Content Page

Tags: webview, maui, .net-7.0

---

Trying to build a content Page with a WebView, DatePicker and button on the same content page. Any time I make the WebView Visible all the other controls become invisible. Have tried many variations but found this layout while googling. Worked for the author but not for me!

Not a lot of info out there on this. Would prefer to use a httpClient but the server I'm hitting requires JavaScript to be enabled. That causes a few issues!

Have tried numerous variations with no luck!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:dxe="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Editors;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Editors"
   xmlns:dxco="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Controls;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Controls"
   xmlns:dxcv="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView;   assembly=DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Pcal.Models"
        
         x:Class="Pcal.Views.GetCal"
         Title="GetCal">

<VerticalStackLayout Spacing="40" Padding="10" Background="white">
    <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="10" >
         


            <dxe:DateEdit   x:Name="CalMonth"
                    PickerActiveViewType="Month"
                    BackgroundColor="white"
                    LabelText="Select Month"
                    LabelFontSize="18"
                    IsLabelFloating="False"
                    IsDateIconVisible="True"
                    ClearIconVisibility="Auto"
                    Margin="10"
                    DisplayFormat="MMMyy" UseNativePicker="true"/>
        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Button Text="Get Calendar" WidthRequest="380"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                    Clicked="OnClicked" 
                    BackgroundColor="Purple" 
                    TextColor="White"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
   

  
        <WebView Source="https://pilot.fedex.com"
                IsVisible="true"
                x:Name="PFCWV1"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                HeightRequest="320"
                WidthRequest="380"
                Navigating="WebViewNavigating"/>
 
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```